# Solving problem using the Principle of Optimality (Suzanne Lenhart Optimal Control Applied to Biological Models Exercise 2.2)

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

How do I approach this problem? I am unsure of the conditions that need to be met in order to apply the Principle of Optimality.

\begin{equation*}
    \underset{u}{\text{min}}\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} 3x(t)^2 + u(t)^2 \, dt
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    \text{subject to}\quad &x'(t) = x(t) + u(t) \text{ and } x(t_0) = x_0 
\end{align*}
For what values of $t_0, t_1$ and $x_0$ can we apply the Principle of Optimality to solve the problem?

Thanks ahead.

--- Additional Information --- 
This is how the theorem was defined in the textbook:
[theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ATv.jpg)

This is the example the question refers to:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGUMi.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is $g(t)$? Also, what principle of optimality are you talking here exactly?

Comment: @KBS Sorry, I made a typo there. It should be u(t). For the principle of optimality, I added how it was defined in the book under additional information. Thanks!

Comment: @CrSb0001: I added the example from the book that this question refers to, as well as the theorem. Hope that clarifies the problem a bit.

Comment: This is called the finite-horizon LQR problem. In your case, there is a unique optimal solution for all initial conditions $x_0$ and all times $t_0<t_1$.

Comment: @KBS: Thanks! So in this case, the constraint for the values of $t_0$ and $t_1$ is that the solution to this problem must be unique?

Comment: No. Uniqueness come from the structure of the problem.